# In a CMD .BAT file, how to turn echo off locally?

Tags: windows-7, cmd

In a CMD .BAT file, how to turn echo off locally i.e. such that upon exit, echo state is restored?

Comment: `@echo off` as first line. Previous state is restored, when the batchfile ends.

Comment: @Stephan: not if the batch file was called from another batch file.

Comment: Can you change the parent batch file?  If you use `cmd /c` instead of `call` the echo state will be restored when the child exits.

Comment: I would rather not change the parent. Plus who knows what else cmd /c might do? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
::call the sub
CALL q25232315s
:: just a command for something-to-do
DIR u:
GOTO :EOF
```

If this is the main routine, then if this is the `call`ed routine:

```dos
@SETLOCAL
@echo>u:\tempfile.txt
@FOR /f "tokens=3delims=. " %%a IN (u:\tempfile.txt) DO @SET state=%%a&@DEL u:\tempfile.txt
@ECHO OFF
:: just a command for something-to-do
DIR u:\destdir
ECHO %state%&EXIT /b
```

It would appear to restore the `echo` state to the caller whilst keeping mum about its own activities.